# Solving integer equation $a^3+b^3=a^2+72ab+b^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all pairs of positive integers $(a;b)$ that satisfy
>   $$a^3+b^3=a^2+72ab+b^2.$$

I have already solved this by letting $S=a+b$, $P=ab$. Then I have $S^3-S^2=(3S+70)P$, which will result in $3S+70$ dividing $5110S$, or $357700$ is divisible by $3S+70$. The result is $(a;b)\in\left\{(1;9),(9;1),(37;37)\right\}$.

However, this strategy is extremely complicated and time-consuming, by listing all divisors of $357700$. I do not know any other way to access this problem. Many thanks.

Comment: Where are the $5110S$ and $357700$ coming from In your answer?

Comment: From $S^3-S^2=(3S+70)P$, we have $(3S+70) | (S^3-S^2) \Longrightarrow (3S+70) | 3(S^3-S^2) \Longrightarrow (3S+70) | S^2(3S+70)-73S^2 \Longrightarrow (3S+70) | 73S^2 \Longrightarrow (3S+70) | \left[ 73S(3S+70) - 5110S \right] \Longrightarrow (3S+70) | 5110S \Longrightarrow (3S+70) | \left[ 5110(3S+70) - 357700 \right] \Longrightarrow (3S+70) | 357700.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $d = (a, b)$, $a = da_0$, $b = db_0$, then $(a_0, b_0) = 1$ and$$
a^3 + b^3 = a^2 + 72ab + b^3 \Longleftrightarrow d(a_0 + b_0)(a_0^2 - a_0 b_0 + b_0^2) = a_0^2 + 72a_0 b_0 + b_0^2, \tag{1}
$$
which implies $a_0 + b_0 \mid a_0^2 + 72a_0 b_0 + b_0^2$. Because$$
(a_0^2 + 72a_0 b_0 + b_0^2) - (a_0 + b_0)(a_0 + 71b_0) = -70b_0^2
$$
and $(a_0 + b_0, b_0) = 1$, then $a_0 + b_0 \mid 70$.

From (1) there is also $a_0^2 - a_0 b_0 + b_0^2 \mid a_0^2 + 72a_0 b_0 + b_0^2$. Because$$
(a_0^2 + 72a_0 b_0 + b_0^2) - (a_0^2 - a_0 b_0 + b_0^2) = 73a_0 b_0,
$$
and $(a_0^2 - a_0 b_0 + b_0^2, a_0) = (b_0^2, a_0) = 1$, analogously $(a_0^2 - a_0 b_0 + b_0^2, b_0) = 1$, then$$
a_0^2 - a_0 b_0 + b_0^2 \mid 73 \Longrightarrow a_0^2 - a_0 b_0 + b_0^2 = 1 \text{ or } 73.
$$

If $a_0^2 - a_0 b_0 + b_0^2 = 1$, then$$
1 = a_0^2 - a_0 b_0 + b_0^2 \geqslant \frac{1}{2} (a_0^2 + b_0^2) \Longrightarrow a_0^2 + b_0^2 \leqslant 2 \Longrightarrow a_0 = b_0 = 1,\ d = 37,
$$
thus $(a, b) = (37, 37)$. If $a_0^2 - a_0 b_0 + b_0^2 = 73$, denote $s = a_0 + b_0$, then$$
\frac{s^2}{4} \leqslant a_0^2 - a_0 b_0 + b_0^2 = 73 < s^2 \Longrightarrow 8 < s < 18.
$$
Note that $s \mid 70$, thus $s = 10$ or $14$. If $s = 10$, then$$
a_0^2 - a_0(10 - a_0) + (10 - a_0)^2 = 73 \Longrightarrow a_0 = 1 \text{ or } 9,\ d = 1,
$$
thus $(a, b) = (1, 9)$ or $(9, 1)$. If $s = 14$, then$$
a_0^2 - a_0(14 - a_0) + (14 - a_0)^2 = 73 \Longrightarrow a_0 = 7 \pm \sqrt{22},
$$
a contradiction. Therefore, $(a, b) = (1, 9),\ (9, 1),\ (37, 37)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=x+y, b=x-y$. Then:
$$a^3+b^3=a^2+72ab+b^2 \Rightarrow \\
(x+y)^3+(x-y)^3=(x+y)^2+72(x+y)(x-y)+(x-y)^2 \Rightarrow \\
2x^3+6xy^2=2x^2+72x^2 -72y^2+2y^2 \Rightarrow \\
y^2=\frac{(37-x)x^2}{35+3x}\ge 0.$$
Note that:
$$x=\frac{a+b}{2}>0 \ \ \text{and} \ \  37-x\ge0  \Rightarrow 0<x\le 37.$$
One can quickly check (if not further analysis) all numbers to find: $(x,y)=(5,4),(37,0)$.

Hence: 
$$(a,b)=(9,1),(37,37) \ \ \text{and} \ \ (1,9) \ \text{(due to symmetry)}.$$